# Error 24 Username and/or password invalid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, informix

I have two instances of IBM Informix Database on a HP-UX UNIX box.  One instance is for test and the other instance is our live database.  The test instance is a copy of the live instance and the usernames and passwords are identical for the two databases.  When I connect to the test instance in Visual Studio 2010 using a drda connection string the connection is successful.  When I connect to the live instance with the same username and password the connection fails with this error:

**ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID"). SQLSTATE=08001.**

The test connection string is:

```
Database=companydb;User ID=dbuser;Password=********;Server=dbserver:1403;Persist Security Info=True
```

The live connection string is:

```
Database=companydb;User ID=dbuser;Password=********;Server=dbserver:1402;Persist Security Info=True
```

The only difference between the two connection strings is the port number.

I have searched the IBM website (nightmare) with no luck.

I have installed IBM Data Server Driver Package - IBMDBCL1, IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio and ClientSDK 3.70 (4.1 doesn't support Visual Studio Add-Ins).

Answer (score 1):

The error is misleading little bit: you just unable to connect. As you know Informix doesn't manage users password: the username and password is inherited from operating system user under which Informix is installed. The simplest way is to install both instances under 2 different operating system users and use different ports. When you able to connect with dbaccess to your DB's under 2 this users you will not have this error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Yuri.  We are currently investigating a DRDA related bug in Informix 11.7 which might be the cause of the issue I have posted.  I will update this question when I have more information.

Comment: It was a bug in the Informix database.